# Specifying type of list objects in the json-ld context

Tags: json-ld

Working with JSON-LD, and trying to create a `@context` that can be external to the main dataset.

I am trying to specify that all elements in a list are of a specified type, something along the lines of this:

```
{
    "@context": {
        "ex": "http://example.org/",
        "group": "ex:group",
        "members": {"@type": "ex:individual", "@id": "ex:member", "@container": "@set"}
    },
    "@type": "group",
    "@id": "ex:mygroup",
    "members": [
        {"name": "John"},
        {"name": "Jeff"},
        {"name": "Jane"}
    ]
}
```

but, I cannot get the `@type` to 'stick', the resulting rdf does not state than John is an individual.

If declaring 'inside' the main part, like this:

```
{
    "@context": {
        "ex": "http://example.org/",
        "group": "ex:group",
        "members": {"@type": "ex:individual", "@id": "ex:member", "@container": "@set"}
    },
    "@type": "group",
    "@id": "ex:mygroup",
    "members": [
        {"name": "John", "@type": "ex:individual"},
        {"name": "Jeff", "@type": "ex:individual"},
        {"name": "Jane", "@type": "ex:individual"}
    ]
}
```

it works, but I would really like to avoid changing the main part of the JSON struct.

The obvious benefit is that I can just tack on a JSON-LD context to an existing interface, for example using a link header.

What am I missing?

Edit: It could be that I am hoping for future functionality as discussed [here](https://github.com/w3c/json-ld-syntax/issues/328).

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is some miss-understanding of json-ld here.
Every object should have type and id. You just can rename them.
So you can do something like:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "class": "@type",
    "Member": {
        "@id": "http://example.org/schema#Member",
        "@context": {
          "name": "@id"
        }
    },
    "members": {
      "@id": "http://example.org/schema#members",
      "@type": "@id",
      "@container": "@list"
    }
 
  },
  "members": [{
    "name": "Jhon",
    "class": "Member"
  }]
}
```

But you can't avoid type definition ‍♂️ it just can't be implicit.